# Little shared property puzzle

Tags: english, language, word-property

What property do the things on this list share?

> 7
>
> W
>
> Spring
>
> Yellow
>
> Rock
>
> Magenta
>
> Gas
>
> Shoulders
>
> Medium

Examples of things **not** on the list:

> Solid
>
> Blue
>
> Paper
>
> 6
>
> Autumn

This list is not exhaustive; I may update the list as I think of more things that fit on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lists identified by El-Guest and we can say the things with the property

> have a different number of syllables than the other elements in their sets.

7 and not 6

> 7 has two syllables while the other numbers 1 to 10 have one.

W

> W has three syllables while the other letters in the alphabet have one.

Spring and not Autumn

> Spring has one syllable while the other seasons Summer, Autumn and Winter have two.

Yellow not Blue

> The primary colors of pigment are simplified as red, yellow and blue: yellow has two.

Rock not paper

> Rock has one while paper and scissors have two.

Magenta

> The secondary colours of light are magenta, yellow and cyan: magenta has three.

Gas not solid

> Gas has one while other states of matter, liquid and solid (even plasma) have two.

Shoulders

> Thanks to El-Guest for this: Head, Shoulders, Knees, and Toes: Shoulders have two.

Medium

> Medium has two while small and large have one.

Comment: I really like this answer @Tom! Very nice :)

Comment: Yellow is kind of special because I can say that it both belongs and doesn't belong on the list depending on circumstances. Anyway, nice job!

Answer (score 4):

Is each item in the list

> Part of a collection of items?

7

> Natural numbers/integers

W

> The alphabet (or W-L-T/W-L-D) (or a direction N-E-S-W from @sensoray -- Thanks!!)

Spring

> Winter, Spring, Summer, or Fall (all you have to do is call ;) )

Yellow

> ROYGBIV, or Cyan-Magenta-Yellow-Black

Rock

> Rock-Paper-Scissors

Magenta

> Magenta-Cyan-Yellow-Black

Gas

> Solid, Liquid, Gas

Shoulders

> Head, Shoulders, Knees, and Toes (Knees and Toes!)

Medium

> Small, Medium, Large

Comment: or a direction, n-e-s-w

Comment: That is a true thing about the list, but not the defining feature.  "Solid," for example, does not fit, nor "S," nor "Blue."  I'll edit the question to make this more clear.

Comment: I should have posted it like that to begin with, it makes a more intriguing puzzle.